# POST or GET request to get info from uploaded file?

Tags: rest

I'm trying to write an API that would receive a PDF file, process it, and send the results back to the user within the same request.

I'm confused as for which request should be used for this task, as the user is trying to GET a response from the server, but they also POST a file.

In this case, should/can I add a PDF file as a parameter to the GET request, or should I use a POST request - but if the latter, how does the user get the processed result?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: A GET request really shouldn't have a body.  Some tools support it, some don't, and there's dissent on whether or not the specifications allow it.  Even if one particular tool allows it, to keep globally standard there just shouldn't be a body.

Comment: @David so that means it should be POST. Does POST also allow for a reply, even if it's like a bigger JSON file?

Comment: @lte__: I don't see why (or how) POST wouldn't allow for a reply.  It's certainly common to POST (or PUT, PATCH, etc.) data to a server and receive a response.  The scenario you're describing is that the user is sending data to the server.  The server can respond to that request however it likes.

Comment: @KJ that literally made no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` is usually used to *get* info that is already on the server, while `POST` is to send information to the server, and the server responds based on that information.

I think your question should be more focused on whether to use `POST` or `PUT`. Take a look at [this guide](https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/), and act according to your case.